# How to skip HTML5 form validation in safari?

Tags: html, safari, mobile-safari

I want to skip validation on a url input/form in Safari. Specifically in Mobile Safari.

From what I can find about the [novalidate attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_form_novalidate.asp) it's not supported in Safari.

Knowing that, how can I skip validation of this url input and/or the entire form? (I could switch it to a text input but I want the url keyboard iOS gives you)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the url easily using a piece of javascript like the one below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function changeInputType()
        {
            if (isBrowserSafari())
            {
                var urlTextBox = document.getElementById("urlInput");
                urlTextBox.type = "text";
            }

        }

        function isBrowserSafari() {
            var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
            if (ua.indexOf('safari') != -1)
            {   
                return ua.indexOf('chrome') <= -1;
            }
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

Feel free to hook up the function to whatever point that makes sense for your program. For instance, onload.

```
<body onload="changeInputType()">
    <form action="#">
        Url: <input type="url" id="urlInput" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function changeInputType()
        {
            if (isBrowserSafari())
            {
                var urlTextBox = document.getElementById("urlInput");
                urlTextBox.type = "text";
            }

        }

        function isBrowserSafari() {
            var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
            if (ua.indexOf('safari') != -1)
            {   
                return ua.indexOf('chrome') <= -1;
            }
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this help.